# Windows server 2012 failover cluster network not working

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, windows-cluster

I had a problem in a network interface of my failover cluster. This cluster is made of 2 nodes and each node has 3 network intefarces, the hearbeat (cross-cable), the lan network and another dedicated interface for virtual machines. Both heartbeat and lan network are clustered.
Yesterday both nodes became unpingable for inside and outside the cluster on the LAN interface, the other interface for VM was working properly.
In Cluster Manager I see that this network become Unreachable for a few seconds, it become up again and than unreachable.... and so on.

I solved by disabling interfaces, setting them to dhcp, reenabling and than reassing a static ip... I think it is strange to have the same problem in both nodes! So I think it is involved the cluster. I updated last week windows OS and hardware's firmware and bios.

These are the events recorded:

```
Error        07/02/2013 12.11.12        FailoverClustering               1127      Network Manager
Cluster network interface 'nodo1 - T02' for cluster node 'nodo1' on network 'LAN' failed. Run the Validate a Configuration wizard to check your network configuration. If the condition persists, check for hardware or software errors related to the network adapter. Also check for failures in any other network components to which the node is connected such as hubs, switches, or bridges.


Error      07/02/2013 12.11.11       FailoverClustering           1129      Network Manager
Cluster network 'LAN' is partitioned. Some attached failover cluster nodes cannot communicate with each other over the network. The failover cluster was not able to determine the location of the failure. Run the Validate a Configuration wizard to check your network configuration. If the condition persists, check for hardware or software errors related to the network adapter. Also check for failures in any other network components to which the node is connected such as hubs, switches, or bridges.


Error      07/02/2013 12.11.11       FailoverClustering           1129      Network Manager
Cluster network 'LAN' is partitioned. Some attached failover cluster nodes cannot communicate with each other over the network. The failover cluster was not able to determine the location of the failure. Run the Validate a Configuration wizard to check your network configuration. If the condition persists, check for hardware or software errors related to the network adapter. Also check for failures in any other network components to which the node is connected such as hubs, switches, or bridges.
```

I don't know if its is important, but Veeam provide backups by this network.
What could it be?

Comment: Error codes/message? Windows Event Log? What in the world lead you do messing about with the IP addresses?? What do you mean the heartbear and lan network are "clustered"?

Comment: What kind of hardware?

Answer (score -1):

Validation reports are really for this. At least, at this time it may be a good idea to, if not already, establish a routine and run validation tests on a regular basis and keep the last few reports around.

Comment: This makes no sense. Perhaps you could expand on this?